# Serious training and fitness for old people

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, age

The over-65 population is growing rapidly and many of us are training seriously and some are competing in sports.

Should old people train differently than young people?  Have there been research studies on training for old people?

Comment: Could you make this question more specific? A good and thorough answer to your question would have to be extremely long, it might be better to narrow it down to a problem you are actually facing. (eg to the sports you are doing). Check the [FAQ], too, especially [this section](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Please consider editing and updating your question to narrow down the scope. A broad and extremely general question, one that can be answered with an entire book, tend to not work well in the Stack Exchange Q&A model. Make it more specific and focus on a more narrow topic to get a better answer. In the meantime, I am going to close this question until it has been improved. Reopening it will be trivial.

Comment: This is an interesting area, focus the question a bit more and it is likely to be reopen.